# How to improve a batched query that is limited by the sort

Tags: sql, sqlite

Im using a batched query to make my application more responsive.  It was an improvement over fetching everything at once, however, when scrolling though the results, there is a noticeable lag on my device (~500ms) while it loads the next set of results.  I have deduced that the sorting is causing the lag (removing the `ORDER BY` resulted in smooth scrolling).

```
SELECT myTable.itemID 
FROM myTable  
ORDER BY myTable.order ASC 
LIMIT 30
```

Then

```
LIMIT 30 OFFSET 30
LIMIT 30 OFFSET 60
etc...
```

The [`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) tells me the its using a temporary binary tree for the order by (despite having an index available).

```
SCAN TABLE myTable (~1000000 rows)
USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

- Can I improve the sorting speed?  From the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) it seam that sorting is `O ( N logN )` no matter if it uses a binary tree or a index.
- Can I avoid doing the sort for subsequent requests.  I.e. somehow re-use the results of the first sort from `LIMIT 30` in the result from `LIMIT 30 OFFSET 30`?
- Is there some other strategy to help?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ScrollingCursor

Comment: @CL. That looks good.  "Do not try to implement a scrolling window using LIMIT and OFFSET" Haha I feel like an idiot :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a column to your data that contains the sort order? Then you could query where sortkey > min and < max for the current fetch, then sort on that subset. Otherwise you're sorting all the data for each query in order to determine the offset starting point, which is never going to be that fast. There are various other options for loading the data...

Run your query without limiting rows. Once you've created a reader, read the first 30 rows, break, do your processing, then just pick up where you left off with the same reader. That sounds more like what you really want.

Alternatively, continue reading in the background into your data structure.

But issuing multiple DB queries isn't going to help if you need to sort and can't otherwise reduce the data set over which sorting needs to occur.